# I have a div that been toggled using jquery but the background color i defined for this div is only visible when i click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just starting with html and JQuery but the title is quite self explanatory. I have 3 images and when i click in one of them it toggles a div that i set with a different background-color, but this color is only visible when i click the images

```js
var source = "";
    
    $('.img-slide-down').click(function () {
        var hidden;
        console.log('hidden: ' + $(".information").is(":hidden"));
        if (source == "" || source == $(this).attr('src')) {
            hidden = $(".information").is(":hidden");
            $('.information').slideToggle();            
        } else {
            hidden = $(".information").is(":hidden");
            $('.information').slideUp();
            $('.information').slideToggle();
        }
        
        videoControl(!hidden);
        source = $(this).attr('src');
            
    });

    function videoControl(bool) {
        var video = document.getElementsByClassName('hmtlVideo')[0];
        console.log(bool);
        if (bool) {
            video.pause();
            video.currentTime = 0;
        } else {
            video.play();
        }
    }
```

```css
body {
        background-color: #2c3d55;
        color: #e8e9f3;
    }
    .border-box {
        border: 2px solid red;
        max-height: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        min-width: 200px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .row-centered {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .col-centered {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        /*text-align: center;*/
    }
    
    .main-content{
        margin-top:3%;
    }
    
    .header {
        background: #393d3f;
        color: #e8e9f3;
    }
    .selected-item {
        border-bottom-color: #4381c1;
    }
    .img-slide-down {
        height: 180px;
        width: 240px;
       
    }
    .img-box{
        position:relative;
    }
    .information {
        margin-top: 1%;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #04395e;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container main-content">
            <div class="row row-centered">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
                    <img class="img-slide-down" src="media/ss_house.jpg"/>         
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
                    <img class="img-slide-down" src="media/ss_road.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
                    <img class="img-slide-down" src="media/ss_water.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="information">
                    <video class="col-md-6 hmtlVideo" controls autoplay>
                        <source src="media/h2oF.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                    </video>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                        consectetur adipiscing elit.
                        Cras sagittis pretium quam quis vehicula.
                        Ut quis tellus et diam tincidunt pretium.
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: soo... you want the background color on the element that slides down to always be on the page, whether there is content in it or not? And you only want the content to toggle when you click on an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are toggling the `div` where `class=information`. If you want the background color to persist. I would create a `div` that wraps `.information` and give it the background color you desire. Give `.information` a transparent background. Like this:

HTML:

```
     <div class="container main-content">
         <div class="row row-centered">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
                <img class="img-slide-down" src="media/ss_house.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
                <img class="img-slide-down" src="media/ss_road.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
                <img class="img-slide-down" src="media/ss_water.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="information-wrapper">
              <div class="information">
                  <video class="col-md-6 hmtlVideo" controls autoplay>
                      <source src="media/h2oF.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                  </video>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                      consectetur adipiscing elit.
                      Cras sagittis pretium quam quis vehicula.
                      Ut quis tellus et diam tincidunt pretium.
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.information {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.information-wrapper {
  margin-top: 1%;
  background-color: #04395e;
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Got it to work using your idea. just switched the css of the wrapper with the information.
And the script i did for toggling the information class is now toggling the wrapper. Thanks a lot